Error encountered while web hosting on Vercel
GET 500 /favicon.png Uncaught Exception {"errorType":"Runtime.MalformedHandlerName","error"}
I Get this error when my node.js express project on vercel
I need to Host my project. So I need to solve this problem. I can't Host this project on Vercel

Maybe you want to put some code here... Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
